# When is the function epilogue executed?

Tags: c, buffer

[image]
Hello I'm analyzing a return to libc attack and found a helpful [website](http://shellblade.net/docs/ret2libc.pdf) with a diagram showing the before (right) and after (left) of a buffer overflow designed for a return to libc attack. The Return address is overwritten with the Address of system.

I dont totally understand the order of execution of the function epilogue. Will the saved value of `ebp` be popped into `ebp` before the function returns to the address of system()? I have read that "function epilogue is executed upon termination of the function". At what point does this function exactly terminate? I don't think it is before calling `system()` because this would mean the overwritten saved ebp containing `4 crappy bytes` would be stored in `ebp`. But I want to make sure. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The image is potentially confusing because it is upside down for the typical layout of a stack diagram (which would have higher memory addresses at the top).

Comment: The document you linked to explains what the 4 crappy bytes do, or at least what the space they occupy is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont totally understand the order of execution of the function
>   epilogue. Will the saved value of `ebp` be popped into `ebp` before the
>   function returns to the address of system()?

Yes.  Returning to the return address is the last action that can reasonably be considered an action of the function rather than of its caller.

> I have read that
>   "function epilogue is executed upon termination of the function". At
>   what point does this function exactly terminate?

What function?  You haven't presented one.  But in general C terms, a function terminates when it executes a `return` statement or when execution of the last statement in its body finishes.  This is the "termination" to which the document refers.

> I don't think it is
>   before calling `system()`

Well then, surprise!  The whole point is that the function *epilogue*, which is executed after the function terminates, causes control to be transferred to the entry point of the `system()` function.  Note, however, that interpreting this correctly requires a split perspective.  Function termination is function specific, and best defined in terms of the function's source code.  The epilogue, on the other hand, has no representation in the source code -- it comprises extra machine instructions inserted by the compiler to implement the function-return semantics of the source language.

> because this would mean the overwritten saved
>   ebp containing 4 crappy bytes would be stored in ebp.

Yes, but it doesn't matter because `esp` is set correctly.  Control then jumps to the entry point of `system()`, where the function prologue sets `esp` as the new `ebp`, and a new `esp` is set.  That function therefore has valid stack bounds, so it runs correctly.  Bad Things may happen when `system()` returns, because the return address is determined by the 4 crappy bytes, but we don't care -- we do all the damage we want to do in the shell that we have induced `system()` to provide to us, before `system()` ever returns.

Answer (score -1):

Function terminates when:

- it executes the return statement function reaches its end (ie there
  are no C statements to execute)